# Как сделать выбор периода в календаре?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, calendar

Есть приложение в котором должна отображаться история за период.
Как организовать выбор этого периода через календарь подобным методом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Находил библиотеки по типу:
MaterialDateTimePicker - но я так в ней и не разобрался. P.S. Можно и с ней помочь разобраться.

Comment: Если есть возможность читать на английском, то вам будет достаточно ознакомиться с этой статьей: https://medium.com/@maithilijoshi94/new-material-date-range-picker-in-android-abd050bfc86d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В видео ниже, отлично описывается работа с Material Design Components в которую входит и работа с выбором диапазона дат.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3yj7JaTTPI

Так же статья которую посоветовал [redlabrat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/304228/redlabrat) тоже помогла.

> Если есть возможность читать на английском, то вам будет достаточно ознакомиться с этой статьей: https://medium.com/@maithilijoshi94/new-material-date-range-picker-in-android-abd050bfc86d